# When should I use props and when should I use state?

Tags: react-native

I don't seem to get when should I use props and when should I use state to store data, and when to use `this` keyword in React Native?

Sometimes when I use the state to store some user entered data, sometimes it is stored and I can find it when I read it from the state but sometimes I find it null, so I was wondering if I'm using the right approach to get the data from the user.

Comment: Use `this` in class based components but not in functional ones State exists in the component where it initialized - when you pass it to another component it is accessible as a prop.

Comment: @stever oh, I get it. Thank you for that. When I pass it to another component as navigation content, right?

Comment: Well you don’t exclusively use it with navigation. When you render the child you pass state as a property. That state is available in the child as prop

Comment: @stever Thank you very much for you answer, it is clear now, thanks again.